# Set model property after button click

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to Razor and as a tutorial kind of project I'm building a calculator application. I have a **working application** where after clicking the " + " submit button the view is refreshed, the calculation is completed and displayed on the screen. The next objective was also completed where the calculation loaded the result in a partial view.

The problem now is that my application only operates under 1 function, ie: " + " (hard coded). But I want it to work with " - ", " * " and " / " aswell. In my Model I defined a property operationType which is now always null.

How do I set a value (" + ", "- ", " * ", "/ ") to the operationType property in my Model through the button click actions (btn-plus, btn-minus, btn-multiply and btn-divide)? So that I can check what operation is asked for in the controller, calculate the right result and then display it.

*I'd like the model properties to remain unchanged.*

**I'm open to any suggestions and/or advice as I'm here to learn. Thanks in advance!**

Master page CSHTML (CalculationMaster.cshtml)

```
<body>
    <div id="containter">
        <h2>Calculator</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("CalculationMaster", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
        <fieldset>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number1) : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number1, new { id = "inputNumber1" })

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number2) : @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number2, new { id = "inputNumber2" })
        </fieldset>
        <div id="dvButtons">
            <ul class="button-block">
                <li><input type="submit" value="+" id="btn-plus" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="-" id="btn-minus" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="*" id="btn-multiply" /></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="/" id="btn-divide" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="dvCalculationResult">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("CalculationPartial", Model); }
    </div>    
</body>
```

Partial View (CalculationPartial.cshtml)

```
<h2>Result</h2>
<p id="result">@Model.Result</p>
```

Relevant Controller code

```
public ActionResult CalculationMaster()
{
    return View(new CalculatorModel());
}
// Post: /Home/CalculationMaster
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculationMaster(CalculatorModel calc)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var num1 = calc.Number1;
        var num2 = calc.Number2;
        /*
        switch (calc.OperationType)
        {
            case "+":
                calc.Result = num1 + num2;
                break;
            case "-":
                calc.Result = num1 - num2;
                break;
            case "*":
                calc.Result = num1 * num2;
                break;
            case "/":
                calc.Result = num1 / num2;
                break;
            default:
                calc.Result = 0;
                break;
        }*/
        calc.Result = num1 + num2;
        this.headCalculation = calc;
        return View(calc);
    }
    return null;
}
public ActionResult CalculationResult()
{
    var model = this.GetCalculatorModel();
    return PartialView("CalculationResult", model);
}
private CalculatorModel GetCalculatorModel()
{
    {
        if(this.headCalculation == null)
        {
            this.headCalculation = new CalculatorModel();
        }

        return this.headCalculation;
    }
}
```

Model (CalculatorModel.cs)

```
public class CalculatorModel
{
    public double Number1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public double Number2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string OperationType
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public double Result
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I've tried modifiying the DOM with Javascript hower the code got stuck in an infinite loop so I removed it from the CalculationMaster.cshtml page. The infinite loop triggered ont eh

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("input#btn-plus").click(function () {
            @Model.OperationType = "+";
            @Html.Action("CalculationMaster", "Home")
        });
        $("input#btn-minus").click(function () {
            @Model.OperationType = "-";
            @Html.Action("CalculationMaster", "Home")
        });
        $("input#btn-multiply").click(function () {
            @Model.OperationType = "*";
            @Html.Action("CalculationMaster", "Home")
        });
        $("input#btn-divide").click(function () {
            @Model.OperationType = "/";
            @Html.Action("CalculationMaster", "Home")
        });
    })
</script>
```

Edit: Suggested Changes by Stephen Muecke

Relevant Controller code (Add string operation parameter)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculationMaster(CalculatorModel calc, string operation)
    {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var num1 = calc.Number1;
           var num2 = calc.Number2;

            switch(operation)
            {
                case "+":
                    calc.Result = num1 + num2;
                    break;
                case "-":
                    calc.Result = num1 - num2;
                    break;
                case "*":
                    calc.Result = num1 * num2;
                    break;
                case "/":
                    calc.Result = num1 / num2;
                      break;
                default:
                    calc.Result = 0;
                    break;
             }

             this.headCalculation = calc;
             return View(calc);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Master page CSHTML (CalculationMaster.cshtml)

```
<div id="dvButtons">
    <ul class="button-block">
        <li><input type="submit" value="+" id="btn-plus" name="operation"/></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="-" id="btn-minus" name="operation"/></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="*" id="btn-multiply" name="operation"/></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="/" id="btn-divide" name="operation"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Give your submit buttons a name (say `name="operation"`) and then add a parameter to your POST method so you can check which button was clicked - `public ActionResult CalculationMaster(CalculatorModel calc, string operation)` (but why do a submit instead of just doing the calculation in the browser)

Comment: I've made the changes that you suggested however the "string operation" parameter in the ActionResult method is null. Also I want to treat the program as a Server-Client kind of application. That's why I don't simply calculate in the browser.

Comment: If you give all your submit buttons the same `name` attribute (and a `value` attribute), the value of the clicked button **will** be posted (assuming your making a normal submit)

Comment: Sorry for the delay I had a meeting. Your last comment made alot of sense to me as I read it. I made the changes and the caluclator is now working, thanks for the help and insight!